# Magento 1.9.2.2 log tables empty

Tags: log

I'm having issue with my `log_customer` & `log_visitor_online` tables, both are empty and aren't saving/updating any records for transactions.

All the other log tables are working well & are updating the data, so Log is not disabled & also `core_config_data` has a value 1 for `dev/log/active`

Comment: See if you have any logs in var folder related to this. Sometimes, Log module suffers from some foreign key violations and tables remain empty.

Comment: system & exception logs are enabled from admin panel but nothing in them related this issue

Answer (score 2):

found the issue, `Enable Log` was set to `Visitors Only` in `Admin > Configurations > System > Log > Enable Log`

It should set to `Yes` if you need customers Log and `No` if you don't need Logs

Answer (score 1):

Check if System > Configuration > Advanced > Mage_Log is enabled.
Check if log observers are disabled in you local.xml or in some external module.
Below are the xml configuration to check if are enabled:

```
 <frontend>
    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch>
            <observers><log><type>enabled</type></log></observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch>
        <controller_action_postdispatch>
            <observers><log><type>enabled</type></log></observers>
        </controller_action_postdispatch>
        <customer_login>
            <observers><log><type>enabled</type></log></observers>
        </customer_login>
        <customer_logout>
            <observers><log><type>enabled</type></log></observers>
        </customer_logout>
        <sales_quote_save_after>
            <observers><log><type>enabled</type></log></observers>
        </sales_quote_save_after>
        <checkout_quote_destroy>
            <observers><log><type>enabled</type></log></observers>
        </checkout_quote_destroy>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

Comment: `Mage_Log` is enabled & I didn't found `<frontend>` tag in my `app/etc/local.xml`
Thanks

Comment: The only thing disabling modules from admin does is stop block output anyway, the rest of the module continues to work as before.

Comment: Try adding that xml before the </config> in the local.xml, clean the cache and test logs.

Comment: nothing happened